# Axios basic HTTP auth asking for credentials twice

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I have an nginx reverse proxy for an application with HTTP Basic Auth set up.
In my frontend web app, the authentication works with axios ( status code 200 ), but after setting the iframe source the browser window asks for the credentials again.
Why is that happening when Im already authenticated ?

[image]

Here is my Vue component.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <v-container>
      <iframe
        v-if="authenticated"
        :src="grafana_url"
        width="450"
        height="200"
        frameborder="0"
      ></iframe>
    </v-container>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
import axios from 'axios';
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      authenticated: false,
      grafana_url: '',
    };
  },
  async created() {
    var self = this;
    var config = {
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'https://grafana.webapp.com',
      auth: {
        username: 'user',
        password: '123456',
      },
    };
    await axios(config)
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.status);
        self.grafana_url =
          'https://grafana.webapp.com/d-solo/panelId=2';
        self.authenticated = true;
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  },
};
```

Comment: HTTP Basic auth requires the credentials on every request. Browsers are able to cache these for you after authenticating the first time but the initial request from Axios does not count since it's not part of the browser's built-in auth system (aka the popup)

Comment: Yes it works when i manually enter the credentials only once.  is there no way to imitate what the browser does in JS ?

Comment: Don't think so. You could always set the URL to `https://user:123456@grafana.webapp.com/d-solo/panelId=2` though such schemes are [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication#access_using_credentials_in_the_url) and might not work properly on all devices

Comment: yes have tried the mentioned method, and although the browser seems to accept the authentication, the webapp errors out for some reason. very weird that it can't be done in js.